# how to change multiple variables of numeric to factors in r?

Tags: r, data-science

Trying to change the certain variables from numeric to factor, but i couldn't apply it to my dataset. 
where:

**hrproj** is the dataset with the columns(variables) numbers - (7,11,14,17,25,26,31) those has to be changed to factors.
Below is the R code:

```
hrfactor <- hrproj[c(7,11,14,17,25,26,31)]
View(hrfactor)

hrproj[,hrfactor]<- lapply(hrproj[,hrfactor], as.factor)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: I think you need `hrfactor <- c(7, 11, 14, 17, 25, 26, 31)`  Then apply `hrproj[,hrfactor] <- lapply(hrproj[,hrfactor], as.factor)`.  Here you have subset the dataset and then used that dataset to subset again?

Comment: You could also use `mutate_at` or `mutate_if`. See this [link](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html)

Comment: super, its working, thanks